# IIS does not lists a website that matches the launch URL - the localhost is not "localhost"

Tags: visual-studio, iis, windows-10, installation, uninstallation

My issue is that Visual Studio 2013 is using my `[asset#].[domain].[country]` as my “localhost” setting. I have to somehow correct Visual Studio to select `localhost` as localhost instead of my `asset#`. This was caused by installation of VS before IIS. The only solution currently I have is to uninstall .NET Frameworks, ASP.Net versions, Visual Studio versions, and IIS then reinstall it all again starting with IIS first.

Here is what Visual Studio generated for my web services URLs (eg):
`https:\\[asset#].[domain].[country]\PALS.Aunthentication\Authentication.svc`

It should be this:
`https:\localhost\PALS.Authentication\Authentication.svc`

Is there an easier solution to this issue?

Comment: I suggest you could try to modify the project properties web tag's server's project url to localhost instead of your domain.

Comment: Thanks Brando, the Web tab URL is actually https:\\localhost\PALS.Authentication\Authentication.svc. However VS runs it as the asset# in place of "localhost". My web.config file also lists the service URLs as https:\\localhost....etc. causing this issue.

Comment: I even tried to "force" the https:\\localhost URL by checking the custom URL checkbox (not sure what the checkbox label) and adding https:\\localhost...etc and that did not work either.

Comment: As far as I know, the localhost without port means it used the 80 port. I suggest you could check your IIS management console's defualt website's web.config file. I guess there is url rewrite rule in it to redirect the request to the asset#.

Comment: Thanks Brando, to clarify further, this is my enterprise pc meaning the substitution for "localhost" is actually my pc asset# and the domain.ca. I've tried searching for this in the registry, VS config files, app config files, IIS config files and cannot find where this is happening. This only happens in Visual Studio. IIS will show https:\\localhost\… when I browse the website through IIS Manager.